# 1/1) BadMethodCallException Method [validator] does not exist. in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

using laravel 5.6 and in my controller I have following code,

```
$input = $request->all();
        $validator = $this->validator($input);

        if ($validator->passes()){
            $booking = $this->create($input)->toArray();
            $booking['link'] = str_random(30);

            DB::table('activations')->insert(['id_user' => $booking['id'], 'token' => $booking['link']]);
            Mail::send('mail.activation', $booking, function($message) use ($booking) {
                $message->to($booking['email']);

                $message->subject('acxian.com - Activation Code');
            });
```

but when I try submit button following error is occurring,

```
1/1) BadMethodCallException

Method [validator] does not exist.
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `validator` method in laravel controllers. To fix this error you can define it by yourself in controller like this:

```
protected function validator($input){
    return Validator::make($input, [
        //array with validation rules
    ]);
```

But the best way to validate form data is using form request object. Read this for more details:   https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation